# Error with Azure AD SingleSignOn

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a subscription to azure and an already developed application, I'm trying to use Azure AD as authentification mechanism.

I created the application in Azure, added Azure AD as authentification mechanism and when I try to log in I get this error.

> AADSTS65005: The app needs access to a service
>   ("http://rts.powerapps.com") that your organization
>   "123-32323-323232-3233" has not subscribed to or enabled. Contact your
>   IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions.

This is my Startup Class.

```
public partial class Startup
{

    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context => 
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:

After removing some app from my required permissions that appeared deleted now I get this error.

[Error Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGVY7.jpg)

EDIT 2:

Fixed after removing and adding the permissions again.

Comment: Thanks, it's my first post.

Comment: You should take the [tour] and read [ask] before posting questions

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you were developing with Common Data Service, based on the service("http://rts.powerapps.com"). Please ensure that that your organization doesn't have the subscribed the service ("http://rts.powerapps.com").

Please note the prerequisites of Common Data Service:

> 1. If you've already signed up for PowerApps, you can go to PowerApps and sign in. If you haven't yet signed up, you can follow these instructions to sign up.
> 2. Make sure that you have admin access to an environment that contains a Common Data Service database. Go to the PowerApps portal, click the gear icon in the upper right of the page, and then click Admin center. If you don't have admin access to any environments that contain a database, follow these instructions to create a database.

And below is helpful document to help get started:

[Get started with the Common Data Service SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-service/entity-reference/cds-sdk-get-started#prerequisites)